# How can I bypass stock tethering app?

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, wifi-tethering

I have a rooted Coolpad catalyst with no cwm. I plan on creating a workaround for cwm but, that's another project. Anyway I have MetroPCS I've tried apps like barnacle, but I get WAN interface not found. It seems newer phones have a guard against root tethering methods, I thought about changing the settings app but can't risk it yet. I am running Android 5.1.1

Comment: Are you running the stock ROM (albeit rooted), or a true open-source ROM like CyanogenMod/LineageOS?

Answer (score 0):

This app [CWM Tether](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.tether&hl=en) should help you.

Comment: I know I can bypass with USB I meant wireless

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer doing this wirelessly, then you will to route your internet traffic via VPN.

You can obtain an Open VPN from playstore (e.g OpenVPN)

Basically whenever you wish to tether you will need to perform this code via terminal:

```
iptables -t filter -F FORWARD
iptables -t nat -F POSTROUTING
iptables -t filter -I FORWARD -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
ip rule add from 192.168.43.0/24 lookup 61
ip route add default dev tun0 scope link table 61
ip route add 192.168.43.0/24 dev wlan0 scope link table 61
ip route add broadcast 255.255.255.255 dev wlan0 scope link table 61
```

Benefits include:

- Secured connections through the tunnel
- Re-routing of traffic simulates a local connection and not tethering

However connections may be slow depending on server chosen.

Alternately you can get [Foxfi Wifi tether](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.foxfi&hl=en)  and is already configured to tether.

*(Disclaimer: This is not a hacking proceedure, carefully read the Ts & Cs of your ISP if they allow tethering with 3rd party applications)*